# Hiding other users' processes on top

Tags: linux, shell, process, top

I'm running a Debian server and giving out shell access for a handful of friends. I'd like to hide the running processes from those normal users, so that for example `top` only shows their own processes, and not anything started by anyone else. Obviously root should see all processes, though.

How would I do this? I've seen it in action on many shared hosting services that offer shell accounts, but haven't come across a way to do it myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only with Linux is not possible. With SeLinux or GrSecurity you can "hide"(in fact, you don't give it access) processes between users. It's a little bit complicated, but not impossible.

Comment: Now it is possible, using `hidepid`: https://serverfault.com/a/909912/12516

Answer (score 1):

There is the command line option -U

> Monitor by user as:  -U somebody
>   Monitor  only processes with a UID or
>   user name matching that given.  This
>   matches real, effective, saved,  and 
>   filesystem UIDs.

or -u

> Monitor by user as:  -u somebody
>    Monitor only processes with an effective  UID  or  user  name
>    matching that given.

How you would effectively enforce this on users who have command line access I don't really know. Given that users have access to the command line they could use a variety of other tools to see other peoples processes anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't interested in SELinux, you could **possibly** get some traction with this problem by getting creative with permissions on the PID subdirectories in /proc/, but some massive testing would have to be done.

Answer (score 1):

A quick and easy way for top, but not bullet-proof, is to give them an alias in their ~/.bashrc (or the shell-specific appropriate startup/alias file) that just runs top looking at their own username:

```
alias top="top -u $USER"
```

This doesn't do anything for `ps` or course, but aside from putting users in a chroot or jail environment, or selinux as Sacx mentioned, there's not a lot that you can do to hide the system from them.

Answer (score 0):

Remounting procfs with `hidepid=1` doesn't require SELinux or GRSecurity, and should be available in recent kernels. Just re-add procfs with the same mount options it has right now, to `/etc/fstab`, or change the existing (unlikely) entry.